# Is there a way to have OTA updates on React Native for tvOS?

Tags: react-native, tvos, ota, code-push, react-native-code-push

We've got an entire suite of iOS/Android apps build on react native and we want to build a tvOS app. It looks like Microsoft's CodePush doesn't support tvOS, which may leave out the option. Is there any way to get OTA updates to a react native tvOS app, or are there other stack options that have OTA updates?